# Time complexity with recursion

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Okay so I need some help with a homework problem I have in my data structures class. We are to code a recursive function for the following.

g(2x)=(2g(x)) / (1+g^2(x))... -1<=x<=1... For |x| < E (epsilon).... E=10^-6.....g(x)=x+x3/6....code for dx=10^-1.

I honestly don't know how to code this recursively. After having running code we are to then write out the time complexity in big oh notation, however I'm still stuck on step one. Any help with explanations would be greatly appreciated as I no a problem along this line will be on the final

Comment: where's your code so far?

Comment: also -- can you write your equation(s) using Google Chart API? (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop over the value of epsilon (or implement it through a recursive call). Once you get your approximation close enough (10^-6) to what you need to approximate, then you stop.

And, the complexity of such a program is somehow linked to the cyclomatic complexity (it is to say, the minimal number of nested loops or recursive calls you need to express your algorithm). In your case, the complexity is in O(n) (if you need only one loop) or O(n^2) (if you need two nested loops).

Note that the `dx` is the step of your approximation function.